# Pyautogui screenshot functions not working while running them on a script

Tags: python, linux, pyautogui, archlinux

The [Screenshot Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) don't seem to be working on my machine.

I already have the requested packages installed:

- scrot
- tk

To my understanding, there's no need to the `python3-dev`, since Arch already has the dev headers within the `python3` package.

Now, to the issue at hand, whenever I attempt to run a *Screenshot Function*, such as `pyautogui.screenshot('$PATH/img.png')` within a script my pointer becomes a **Crosshair** and I get the following error:

> Syntax error near unexpected token "$PATH/img.png"

However, whenever I run the same line from within, I do not know the appropriate name for it but, let's call it *Python's Shell*. You know, whenever one calls `python` from the terminal. It works.

My issue is that, I'd prefer to avoid typing my commands within the *Python Shell* every time. Any ideas on how to debug this? I'm completely blank at this point, which is why I come here, I couldn't find this specific error online.

Edit: I'm not married to the idea of using `pyautogui` for this, if any of you have any ideas for similar tools that work on Arch, I'm all ears!

Comment: You're somehow running your code as a shell script rather than as Python code.  You haven't shown enough details to tell why this is happening.

Comment: Tha's exactly the case! Totally forgot that the script should have been run with Python. Sorry, it's been a while. Please make this comment an answer, so that I may point it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jasonharper's comment I realized that what I was attempting to do was wrong.

My script required a very important first line, the shebang.

`#!/path/to/bin/python`

Now I may run the python script as I would any other bash script.

Comment: Yes, the shebang line is needed if you want to run the Python script from the terminal by just entering the script's name like `./yourscript.py`. The shebang line tells the terminal to use Python to run it, otherwise it treats your Python code as a shell script, and then gives you a syntax error. You can skip the shebang line if you enter `python3 yourscript.py`.